# How to Display image from Menu Image in Walker Dropdown Select Menu

Tags: plugins, images, walker, select

Created a custom menu list, titled Country that has flags representing countries (only Canada and USA) using the plugin [Menu Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-image/)

I combined this menu with Walker, to create a dropdown. I however can only access the title assigned to the images, and cannot find out where the image information is actually stored within the `$item`.

Here is the Walker Class the I have used, this displays the Title of the selected item in the dropdown.

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth){
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth); // don't output children opening tag (`<ul>`)
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth){
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth); // don't output children closing tag
    }
    /**
    * Start the element output.
    *
    * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
    * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
    * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
    * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
    * @return void
    */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            //var_dump($item); exit;
            foreach ($item as $key=>$value){
                if(strpos(strtolower((string)$value),"anada")!== false){
                    echo $key .":".$value."&&";
                }
            }
        $url = '#' !== $item->url ? $item->url : '';
        $output .= '<option value="' . $url . '">' . $item->title;
               // $item->image;
    }   
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
        $output .= "</option>\n"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
    }
}
```

The call to this class is made inside my theme like so:

```
 <?php 
// Nav Menu Dropdown Class
include_once( '/lib/classes/nav-menu-dropdown.php' );

wp_nav_menu( array(
    // 'theme_location' => 'mobile',
    'menu'           => 'Country',
    'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown(),
    'items_wrap'     => '<div class="mobile-menu"><form><select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">%3$s</select></form></div>',
) );
?>
```

I have var_dumped information but I found nothing to assist me. I also output the menu using the standard method of  `wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Country'));`

This above displays the menu images that I would like to see in my dropdown, and I know where the images are stored, but I want to access it from the `$item` when I am building my walker dropdown

**Update 1:** Modification to `function start_el`

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            $menuImage = new Menu_Image_Plugin();
            $menuImage->menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter($output2, $item, $depth, $args);
            var_dump($output2);
            $url = '#' !== $item->url ? $item->url : '';
            $output .= '<option value="' . $url . '">' . $output2;
                   // $item->image;
        }   
        function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
            $output .= "</option>\n"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
        }
    }
```

Output from `$menuImage->menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter()` was `NULL`.

**Update 2**

Reviewed the function of `menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter` in menu_image.php

```
 function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
                $image_size = $item->image_size ? $item->image_size : apply_filters( 'menu_image_default_size', 'menu-36x36' );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $item->thumbnail_id, $image_size, false, "class=menu-image {$class}" );
            var_dump($image); //read string out
            echo $image;   //displays the image
                $url = '#' !== $item->url ? $item->url : '';
                $output .= '<option value="' . $url . '">' . $image;
                       // image is not being included in $output
            }   
            function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
                $output .= "</option>\n"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
            }
        }
```

The image is still not included in the output?

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in metadata, there are four meta fields: `_thumbnail_id` and `_thumbnail_hover_id` - store attachment ID, `_menu_item_image_size` - store selected image size, `_menu_item_image_title_position` - store label position, but you can get stored values from this properties:
`$item->thumbnail_id`, `$item->thumbnail_hover_id`, `$item->image_size`, `$item->title_position`. Check the `menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter()` function in menu-image.php

Comment: Inside the `function start_el`  I created a `$menuImage = new MenuImage();`
which called the `menu_image_nav_menu_item_filter()` . The output returned was output2 and I used that output to replace `$item->title` , however the output2 was null, so the drop downs were empty.

Comment: I displayed the code changes above.

Comment: You don't need to create instance of MenuImage class, if this module is activated, it should work. Or if you want to access instance directly, you can use `global $menu_image;`, I guess. Anyway try to get metadata directly: `$item->thumbnail_hover_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_thumbnail_hover_id', true );`

Comment: Got ya, but the `$item->thumbnail_hover_id` you detail above is the same as the `$item->thumbnail_id` I have finally got the image after reviewing the method you mentioned but it still in not appearing within html `<option>` please refer to **update 2** in my original post

Comment: Html element `<option>` didn't support anything inside except plain text. You can use any icon-font there, or create your one.

Comment: Yeah I googled that so I have been changing the structure to use a bootstrap drop down! :) I'll update my solution once complete